# noUiSlider doesn't retain values

Tags: jquery

I am using the noUiSlider in a form which sends the chosen values to two input fields which are then submitted through the form.

This works fine but when the form is submitted and results are displayed, the input fields and slider default back to the original values rather than retaining the previously selected.

Here is the code:

```
function leftValue(value, handle, slider) {
    $(this).text(handle.parent()[0].style.left);
}
$("#slider").noUiSlider({
    connect: true,
    snap: true,
    start: [0, 1000],
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        '10%': 100,
        '20%': 200,
        '30%': 300,
        '40%': 400,
        '50%': 500,
        '60%': 600,
        '70%': 700,
        '80%': 800,
        '90%': 900,
        'max': 1000
    },
    serialization: {
        lower: [
            $.Link({
                target: $('#minprice')
            }),
        ],
        upper: [
            $.Link({
                target: $('#maxprice')
            }),
        ],
        format: {
            decimals: 0,
        }
    }
});


<div id="slider"></div>
  <input type="text" id="minprice" name="minprice">
  <input type="text" id="maxprice" name="maxprice">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In version 7 of noUISlider serialization has been replaced by `Link`.

Have a look at the following code

```
    container.noUiSlider({
        range: {
            'min': min,
            'max': max
        },
        step: step,
        start: initial,
        connect: 'lower',
        format: {
            to: function (value) {
                return value;
            },
            from: function(value) {
                return value
            }
        }
    });

    container.Link('lower').to(field);
```

Relevant docs are here: http://refreshless.com/nouislider/linking-input-fields/

Comment: Thanks, I didn’t know it had been changed. I have used the SESSION PHP function to retain the values in the min and max input fields but the slider javascript code,  start: [0, 1000], overrides the retained input values?